# error compiling opencv example

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to compile an example that is provided for one of the opencv_contrib modules (text detection module). The link is below:
https://github.com/Balaje/opencv-1/blob/master/samples/cpp/textdetection.cpp

I keep getting errors like:  error: ‘ERStat’ was not declared in this scope

I have already compiled and installed opencv_contrib modules and I see text.hpp in /usr/local/include/opencv2. I included text.hpp as well, but I got the same errors. Does anybody know how I can fix the problem?

I compile the file with the following command:
g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` -o textdetection textdetecti
on.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing all `ERStat` in the code with `cv::text::ERStat`. It should solve the problem.